# Shortcut to toggle a specific combination of layers?

Tags: add-on, shortcut, layers

Is there some way to toggle a specific combination of layers (instead of all layers, or one layer at a time)?

For example, let's say I have objects in layers 1 to 5, and I occasionally want to hide layers 2, 3 and 4 (or maybe sometimes I want to see 2, 3 and 4, and hide 1 and 5). How can I toggle 2, 3 and 4 together with one shortcut?

Ideally, a way to set multiple combinations instead of just one combination.

I know the <kbd>`</kbd> key toggles all layers, and the number row keys can toggle individual layers.

Answer (score -1):

The only way possible would be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, I think.